# phpMyEdit Login Failed?

Tags: php, mysql

I recently downloaded phpMyEdit which is a GUI script to create/edit MySQL database tables and fields.

I uploaded the script to my server. I read the installation doc, and it doesn't require anything to be added to any file... just open phpMyEditSetup.php in the browser and add my database hostname, username and password. The problem is that, when I enter the information and click submit, I get an error message saying "login failed - try again".

I tried it on 2 different hosts and it's not working. I'm pretty sure that the database username, password and hostname I provided is correct.

Is there anyone that has faced this problem before and found a solution? If so, can you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some things to try:

1. [phpMyEdit Installation Doc](http://opensource.platon.sk/projects/doc.php/phpMyEdit/html/installation.html) - ***Important:*** Before uploading the program files to your server, make certain that your FTP client is not configured to force filenames to lower case letters.
2. Are you using phpMyAdmin? If so, you can use it to help make sure you have the correct hostname and username for your connection. **Example:**
   [image: phpMyAdmin Example]
3. You can also use phpMyAdmin to look at the specs for your web server and make sure they meet the [requirements of phpMyEdit](http://opensource.platon.sk/projects/doc.php/phpMyEdit/html/introduction.requirements.html).
4. Make sure you have read the [phpMyEdit Documentation](http://opensource.platon.sk/projects/doc.php/phpMyEdit/html/index.html)
5. Finally, if all else fails, contact your hosting provider or web server administrator to retrieve your db hostname, username, and possibly have them reset your db password. Also, discuss the [requirements of phpMyEdit](http://opensource.platon.sk/projects/doc.php/phpMyEdit/html/introduction.requirements.html) with them to be sure your web server is compliant.

Comment: Well, your links helped me ! on the official page of phpmyedit they dont have the newset version and the version posted there is messed up... so by clicking on the link of the documentation, i found a download page and i downloaded the newest verion 5.7 and it works perfectly. If anybody has the same problem that the correct download page (http://opensource.platon.sk/projects/release_list_page.php?project_id=5) Thank you! :)

Comment: opensource.platon.sk is down when I checked today. Current versions from their CVS page are: * phpMyEdit version: 5.7.1+ * phpMyEdit.class.php core class: 1.216 * phpMyEditSetup.php script: 1.51 * generating setup script: 1.51